# ServiceNow: How to autofill a survey using link parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, servicenow, jelly

[Original Post on ServiceNow Forums](https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=48d59d27db502010b1b102d5ca9619d9)

I am a beginner to the ServiceNow platform, and have been trying to automate the following:

I'm trying to send an email when an incident is closed with two links to the same survey.

The first link should automatically click 'Yes' and the second should automatically click 'No' on the first question of the survey. After a lot of Google searches i found a few tutorials which I've put up [here](https://www.notion.so/ServiceNow-a4935559e7bc4f36a9688d5166b5357a). They haven't helped much with solving my problem.

### Problem

When I followed the steps for [this tutorial](https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=32f20ba1dbd8dbc01dcaf3231f961948) I only got an [unexpected failure error](https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=e46807eddb1cdbc01dcaf3231f9619eb) on the UI page I had modified, which I could not understand. I tried resetting my personal developer instance and doing the same steps again, but it gave the same results.

Is there any newbie friendly explanation of how to do these things? is there just a simpler way to achieve this which I have missed?